# How to disable (HTTP/HTTPS) Proxy and SOCKS proxy on MAC using terminal while on recovery mode?

Tags: macos, terminal, socks-proxy, http-proxy

I use networking sniffing tool Charles Proxy to check my app traffic. However, after updating my mac, for some reason the HTTP/HTTPS and Socks proxy is turned on. If I restart my mac my network is not connected unless I turn on Charles Proxy, which is keeping me locked out.

How do I turn it off the proxy settings from the terminal while inside the recovery mode?

Comment: How does not being able to connect before login prevent you from logging in & changing it there?